# Count percentage in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this SQL query where its most important function is to return the total sales made `SUM(gop.quantity)`. I would then like it to show the percentage for this number. If the query returned the following 3 rows then it should show the percentage next to it - like this:

- unitsSold : 2 - percentage: 20%
- unitsSold : 4 - percentage: 40%
- unitsSold : 6 - percentage: 60%

Query:

```
SELECT TOP 20 
    p.productid, 
    SUM(gop.quantity) AS unitsSold, 
    SUM(gop.price * gop.quantity) AS grossSales, 
    p.productName, gop.picid, gop.picUrl 
FROM 
    product AS p 
LEFT JOIN 
    orderdetail AS gop ON gop.productid = p.productId 
LEFT JOIN 
    Orders AS hedgo ON hedgo.orderid = gop.orderid 
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM orderdetail AS op 
            WHERE op.orderid = hedgo.orderid) 
GROUP BY 
    p.productid, p.productName, gop.picid, gop.picUrl 
ORDER BY 
    unitsSold DESC
```

How can I accomplish this in my SQL query?

Comment: what is your formula for the percentage? unitsSold/totalUnitsSold?

Comment: yes that's the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sum()` with  [**`over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to get the total:

```
select top 20 p.productid
 , SUM(gop.quantity) as unitsSold
 , SUM(gop.quantity+.0) / sum(SUM(gop.quantity)) over() as Percentage
 , SUM(gop.price * gop.quantity) as grossSales
 , p.productName
 , gop.picid
 , gop.picUrl
from product as p
  left join orderdetail as gop 
    on gop.productid = p.productId
  left join Orders as hedgo 
    on hedgo.orderid = gop.orderid
where exists (
  select *
  from orderdetail as op
  where op.orderid = hedgo.orderid
  )
group by p.productid
 , p.productName
 , gop.picid
 , gop.picUrl
order by unitsSold desc
```

I added `+.0` to the `sum(gop.quantity)` so that the division operation would return a `decimal` instead of an `int`, if `quantity` is an `int`.